# How install Xcode on a macOS 10.13 via workstation

Tags: xcode, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

At the moment, I would like to code something for ios just for fun and to learn new things. I have a VM Workstation 15 Pro, but I only have a macOS 10.13 system for use, so if I run it von my Workstation and try to install Xcode he won't let me, because then the only message I get is:

> "can only be installed on 10.13.6 version"

How and where can I get this version (without the help of Apple ...) or is there a way to avoid all this?

Answer (score 0):

Update the macOS version in your VM from 10.13 to 10.13.6. Open the Mac App Store in your 10.13 VM and check for updates. From there you should be able to update your VM to 10.13.6, allowing you to install Xcode.

Another alternative is to install an older version of Xcode from [Apple's developer site](https://developer.apple.com/xcode).

Answer (score 0):

In order to download older versions of XCode you have to have an apple account and then sign the developer TOS to access old versions of software [in the downloads -> more section of the developer site at apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/). You can determine which version of XCode will be compatible with your version of mac OS by referring to the column "min macOS to run" in the tables [on the wikipedia page for XCode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode#Version_comparison_table)

If you want to download it without Apple you will probably have to find an alternate source to download XCode (which I'm guessing breaks their TOS)